# Not getting all UITableViewCell from UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom cell within my UITableView with a textField in it. I'm trying to read the textFields' values from table view.

To get the cells and values from textFields, I'm using the below code:

```
for var i = 0; i < myTableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0); i++ {  //5 records

    let index: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
    //getting the cell at position i 
    let cell = self.myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(index) as! myCustomCell
    //Read data
    let newValue = cell.myTextField.text

}
```

I'm not getting any compiler errors, but when I run the application, it sometimes fails at cell index 0, sometimes at cell index 3, it is at a random position.  The error I'm getting is:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Which I understand because the cell is not present within myTableView.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to be able to read all the custom cells from my table view?

Comment: Whenever possible, read the values from the model (data source array) rather than from the view (table view cell).

Comment: have you given outlet to the text field in the cell class

Comment: Yes, the oulets are in place, and Im reading from the tableview directly because the user is able to change the textfield values.  So I wanted to read these new values and update my data model.

Comment: Better choice is as vadian suggested, store data in model, not cells, because cells can be reused or overwritten. Assign your view controller as delegate to UITextField and adopt UITextFieldDelegate. You can give textfields tags to distinguish between them, or just check the indexPath for it by figuring coordinates of the textfield inside table view. When user finishes editing textfield's text, save that in the model.

Comment: As others have said you should use a data model. There is a nice framework for dealing with this sort of problem called Bond. You can read about using it here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/123108/bond-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewCells are getting recycled. That's why its not safe to do it your way. You need to use a Data Model as others already pointed out.